# Can jQuery Masonry orient divs vertically instead of horizontally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-masonry

I hope someone can help me.
I am using jQuery Masonry to align divs in a grid. The only problem is that the orientation is not right for me.

Masonry aligns the blocks like:

```
1234
5678
```

I need the blocks to align like:

```
1357
2468
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, eventually I just switched the blocks around e.g I moved div 3 to position 2 etc. Its going to vary in different browser sizes anyway.

Comment: Right! Masonry will push blocks down if any of it is bigger in size. He only can obtain that by using normal CSS. By using `max-width` and `max-height`

Comment: I was hoping to find an option in the Masonry API to solve it but there's no option. I think I might try write my own script to pop the divs onto the next line.